# How to show the regression line in seaborn linear regression jointplot

Tags: python, regression, seaborn

As described in the [seaborn API](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) the following code will produce a linear regression plot.

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
# loading dataset 
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
  
# draw jointplot with reg kind 
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", kind="reg")
```

[This is the regression plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjNpY.jpg)

Unfortunately there is no regression line. How can I add a line like in the [API](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)?

Comment: This is strange. I tried the code you shared and I can see a line in the plot. I am using a Jupyter Notebook. I would suggest that you check if you have the lastest versions of both packages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updating these packages couldn't help me.

Comment: I am sorry, that was all I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried to use `regplot()`

```
sns.regplot(x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", data=penguins)
```

But it also didn't show the line. But using it in combination with `jointplot`:

```
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", kind="reg")
sns.regplot(x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", data=penguins)
```

[The result with the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Pbb.png)

Comment: I 
was looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
 try JointGrid it combines two plots into one.  In this cat a regplot and a distplot.  The regplot shows the linear regression trend and the distplot shows the data distribution in one graph
 import scipy.stats as stats

 g=sns.JointGrid(data=df, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm")
 g.plot(sns.regplot, sns.distplot)

 or

 g=g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot)
 g=g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot,shade=True)
 g=g.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful